# Returning hash of static functions is empty object

Tags: javascript, static, ecmascript-6

I am trying to call draw functions dynamically based on a key.

When I log out renderFunctions, it shows as an empty Object {}.

I'm expecting the functions to be inside with the keys 'ship' and 'ball'.

```js
    class Render {
      static renderFunctions() {
        return {
          'ship': this.drawShip,
          'ball': this.drawBall
        };
      }

      static render(key, ls, context, portal) {
        let renderFns = this.renderFunctions();
        console.log(renderFns);
      }

      static drawShip(ctx, p, t) {
        p.drawRect(ctx, t.x - 5, t.y - 100, 10, 100, t.teamColor);
      }

      static drawBall(ctx, p, t) {
        ctx.arc(t.x, t.y, 7, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = t.teamColor;
        ctx.fill();
      }
    }
```

Why are my functions not showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't refer to static functions as properties of `this`, but as properties of your class (i.e. `Render`).

```
class Render {
    static renderFunctions() {
        return {'ship' : Render.drawShip,
       'ball' : Render.drawBall};
    }

    static render(key, ls, context, portal) {
        let renderFns = Render.renderFunctions();
        console.log(renderFns);
    }

    static drawShip(ctx, p, t) {
        p.drawRect(ctx, t.x - 5, t.y - 100, 10, 100, t.teamColor);
    }

    static drawBall(ctx, p, t) {
        ctx.arc(t.x, t.y, 7, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = t.teamColor;
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
```

Comment: @quantumpotato Try clicking that `Object {}` in console, you should see your functions.

Comment: and then I can call them directly with renderFns[key]( ... ) ?

Comment: @quantumpotato Yes. For example you can do `renderFns.ship(...)` or `renderFns['ball'](...)`.